# Detecting the size of a users finger on touch

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I was wondering if there is a way to find out the size of a persons finger when they touch an android device. I want to know this so i can change the sensitivity of certain objects in my game.

Comment: does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422400/android-measure-detect-covered-area-by-a-finger-touch-on-screen-not-only-touch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution for devices that don't offer the touch.getSize() function, you can have on the start screen a high resolution plot of 2d points. On touch, detect the ones touched and there you can have a pretty accurate area of how big the finger is.